# Protocol for Adding people on Linkedln

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, job-search, linkedin, phone

Is it unreasonable to add a person on linkedln that interviewed you? I want to add a person who did a phone interview with me. Is this seen as a bad gesture?

Comment: I have had the interviewer invite me, the potential job candidate, on LinkedIn. I was uncomfortable accepting the invite because I wasn't ready to make the connection. I didn't want them to see other people I was interviewing with.

Answer (score 11):

It's very normal and very common.

It's become an acceptable and public way to check someone out in more detail and vica-versa.

It communicates a "I'm still quite interested in the job after the call".

It's frequently seen as providing immediate references (including actual recommendations on linkedIn) and many folks can create resume's there too.

Comment: Durant: So it is better than just sending a thank you email? Also this was a phone screening. Sending an invitation wouldn't hurt?

Comment: Durant: Also I don't know whether I have the job yet. There is still more interviews to follow.

Comment: Sure doing it before any offers means each side is taking the chance to learn more and do due diligence.

Comment: Basically, go ahead.  If they don't accept it's a useful indicator of a lack of further interest.  Yes, it won't hurt (usually).

Comment: I agree with Michael's answer.  @PaulJames, to your comment about "better than just sending a thank you," I would say no -- a LinkedIn invite should not be used in lieu of a thank-you, but you could combine the two with your invite text: "Thank you for the interview...please  join my LinkedIn network (etc)". Maybe not those exact words, but you get the idea. :)

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to play it by ear, and take refusal with a grain of salt.

Some companies advise against such links to insulate hiring managers from the expectation of followup after the interview.  Others don't care or may even encourage the link.

If you had a good rapport with the person, if they stuck out to you as particularly worth keeping contact with - then give it a shot, but don't be upset if you get ignored.  Conversely, I'd advise against doing it just because you had an interview - because it's pretty likely that in 3 years you won't have any idea who these people were, or why they mattered - and LinkedIn is really geared towards sustaining professional connections...

If you'd prune your connection tree of this guy if you don't get the job, I'd say don't invite in the first place.  If you think that 3 months down the line, you'd want to read a status update from him - then go for it.

Answer (score 6):

As an interviewer I would not be a fan of this.

My feeling is that LinkedIn is a way to form a network of trusted colleagues. After one interview I am not really a colleague of yours and certainly haven't formed a trust relationship.

It would seem to me a bit awkward. I would not hold it against you in terms of the interview process, but I would not accept the invite.

Comment: +1 - Indeed. I don't have a problem with someone hunting down my linked-in account (as an interviewer, I will usually look at a candidate's page to know if we share any 'friends'), but an invite is too presumptive after a basic interview.